# How do you document a tree-to-tree transformation in a human-readable format?

Tags: web-services, xslt, data-structures, soap

I need to document an application that serves as a facade for a set of webservices. The application accepts SOAP requests and transforms these requests into a format understandable by the underlying web service. There are several such services, each with its own interface. Some accept SOAP, some HTTP POST, some... other formats not mentioned in polite society.

I need to document how we map the fields from our SOAP calls to the fields for these other formats. Before everyone cries "XSLT" I must mention that the notation must be human-friendly. Ideally it would be something Excel-able.

Has anyone encountered this sort of problems before? How did you solve it? Is there a human-friendly notation for tree-to-tree transformations that can fit on a spreadsheet?

Comment: XSLT! (Sorry, but I could not resist :D)

Comment: Just that I understand it - do you only need to *document* it (e.g. make a read-only representation), or do you need to create a workable transformation solution based on a list that contains field mappings in a simple format?

Comment: @Tomalak I really only need to docment it. What we started out with was an Excel spreadsheet with one row per field (and its XPath), and another column telling what it was mapped to. But this becomes easily unreadable and does not work well with more complicated structures.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do just this. The way I did it was to just start writing, following the hierarchical structure.

I eventually would find that I was repeating myself. An example was that certain elements had a common set of attributes. I would pull the documentation of that common set up before the sections on the specific elements. Same thing with documentation of handling of specific simpleTypes.

Eventually, there was even some high level discussion on the overall flow and "philosophy" of the transformation. But I let it all happen bit by bit, fixing it as I became bored with repetition.

That said, I'm a developer, not a tech writer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really found anything so far, but I've found pointers to many libraries that help transform objects of one type to another in Java. For reference, I'm listing the most promising ones here, all doing some kind of JavaBean to JavaBean conversion:

- [Transmorph](http://transmorph.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
- [EZMorph](http://ezmorph.sourceforge.net/)
- [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)